# Spritekit Editor Resize Action doesn't resize Body

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I'm new using the SpriteKit Editor within XCode. I applied a `resizeToWidth` action to a simple `Color Sprite` Node. The Node has a physics body of the type `bounding rectangle`. The problem is the graphical representation is resizing but not it's body. The body just stays the same. See the result after applying the action, red is the sprite and the blue line it's bounding box.

[image]

How can I make sure that the physics body is resizing like the sprite?

Comment: If I use the ScaleTo Action, the physics body resizes appropriately.

Comment: physics body is not tied directly to sprites, so you are going to have to manually adjust the body after you adjust the sprite sometimes

Comment: thanks for your answer. but why is the body resized when I scale it? I know I could do it in code. also when i rotate it rotates with the sprite. all in the sprite kit editor.

Comment: you mean with the action?  Because actions are not part of SKSpriteNodes methods, so it makes sense to scale everything attached with it.  but to resize a sprite, do you always want to resize the body since the body is a separate thing,  perhaps not

Comment: yes i mean the action. the rotation action and scale actions change the body to but the resizeToWidth doesn't.

Comment: oh you are using a resizeToWidth action, thought it was a different method, never mind on that

Comment: yeah just looked it up,  resizeToWidth only changes the size property of the sprite,  so physics body would not look at that to get changed.

Comment: thanks again, i looked it up too. just don't understand why it is different from the others actions...

Comment: size doesn't affect the matrix of the sprite